# How to delete all oldest records until the SUM of some numerics fields reaches a certain values (TOT)

Tags: mysql

In a `MySQL 5.0`'s table, I wish delete the oldest record until the *SUM of some numeric fields reaches a certain values* called TOT (some threshold).

I have the following fields in the table:

```
ID, field0 (varchar), field1 (INT), field2 (INT), field3 (int), date
```

I need a query to select all the oldest record until a sum value (TOT) is reached

```
SELECT ID, SUM(field1,field2,field3) as TOT 
    WHERE field0 = '$username' .... ORDER BY date ASC
```

The Purpose: To delete older records until the SUM of the 3 numeric fields reaches a certain values TOT.

Any tips?
thanks

Comment: what's the nature of the `SUM(field1, field2, field3)` across records against date?

Comment: View this [question: Query: All employee with sum of salary > 500](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33497/query-all-employee-with-sum-of-salary-500)

Answer (score 0):

This is a place to implement [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-syntax.html)

1. You could get the total record set,
2. ordered by id or insert-date, and
3. continually sum the fields until you hit your target total, then
4. take latest in your ordered list, and
5. delete everything outside of that range.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the cumulative sum this way:

```
SELECT ID,
       (select SUM(field1 + field2 + field3) from t t2 where t2.date <= t.date and t2.field0 = tempdb.field0) as cumsum
from t
WHERE field0 = '$username'
```

I think the following works in MySQL to do the delete:

```
delete from t
where t.id in (select id
               from (SELECT ID,
                            (select SUM(field1 + field2 + field3) from t t2 where t2.date <= t.date and t2.field0 = tempdb.field0) as cumsum
                     from t
                     WHERE field0 = '$username' 
                    ) tsum
                where cumsum <= YOURTHRESHOLD
              )
```

MySQL is finicky about self joins in `delete` statements.  I think the double subquery fixes this problem.

Note:  this code is untested so may contain syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not given you actual table description of your table. In my answer I am using a `Worker` in my `COMPANY` Database:

In my `Worker` table I have three salary fields similarly you `field1`, `field2` & `field3`. The actual description is as following:

```
mysql> DESC `Worker`;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN     | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| name    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary1 | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary2 | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| salary3 | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Date    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In this table I added `Date` as integer (you can have actual *data type* available in MySQL).

Suppose table has following tuples:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `Worker` ORDER BY `Date` ASC ;
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+
| SSN | name    | salary1 | salary2 | salary3 | Date |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+
| 3   | Sumit   |     250 |     150 |     100 |    2 |
| 4   | Harsh   |     500 |    -150 |     900 |    2 |
| 5   | ONE     |     100 |     170 |     100 |    9 |
| 2   | Rahul   |     300 |      15 |      30 |   10 |
| 1   | Grijesh |     200 |     100 |      50 |   13 |
| 7   | THREE   |    1000 |      17 |    -200 |   21 |
| 6   | TWO     |      50 |    -170 |     200 |   27 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+
```

<sub>ASC order show in above query</sub>, <sub>Date is in type as I said</sub>

Suppose I need to remove all *old* Workers those have sum of their salary just more then `N` (`N` is like threshold TOT in your case). To select older workers I required to sort `Worker` table in  assenting (*ASC*) order.

<sub>Date you can assume as date of joining in Company of a worker. So **old is according to date of joining** that's experience</sub>

Before to write selection query I show you some results:

```
mysql> SELECT * , `salary1` + `salary2` + `salary3` AS TSalary  
    -> FROM `Worker` ORDER BY DATE ASC ; 

+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| SSN | name    | salary1 | salary2 | salary3 | Date | TSalary |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| 3   | Sumit   |     250 |     150 |     100 |    2 |     500 |
| 4   | Harsh   |     500 |    -150 |     900 |    2 |    1250 |
| 5   | ONE     |     100 |     170 |     100 |    9 |     370 |
| 2   | Rahul   |     300 |      15 |      30 |   10 |     345 |
| 1   | Grijesh |     200 |     100 |      50 |   13 |     350 |
| 7   | THREE   |    1000 |      17 |    -200 |   21 |     817 |
| 6   | TWO     |      50 |    -170 |     200 |   27 |      80 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`TSalary` is tatal salary a worker get as his employment that is sum of three components of `salary1`, `salary2` & `salary3` (*as shown in above query*)

What is sum of salary at each level (for each subset of table):

```
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+
| SSN | name    | salary1 | salary2 | salary3 | Date | TSalary | SUM(TSalary) at
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+ each level
| 3   | Sumit   |     250 |     150 |     100 |    2 |     500 |500
| 4   | Harsh   |     500 |    -150 |     900 |    2 |    1250 |500 + 1250= 1750
| 5   | ONE     |     100 |     170 |     100 |    9 |     370 |1750 + 370= 2120
| 2   | Rahul   |     300 |      15 |      30 |   10 |     345 |2120 + 345= 2465
| 1   | Grijesh |     200 |     100 |      50 |   13 |     350 |2465 + 350= 2815 
| 7   | THREE   |    1000 |      17 |    -200 |   21 |     817 |2815 + 817= 3632
| 6   | TWO     |      50 |    -170 |     200 |   27 |      80 |3632 + 80 = 3712
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+------+---------+
```

And I have written a Query to select old worker having sum of their salary `<= N`.

`N = 1500` is below example:(*as I calculated above I guess two row should be select*)

```
SELECT `ssn`, `name`, `salary1` , `salary2` , `salary3` 
FROM ( SELECT `ssn`, 
              `name`, 
              `salary1` , 
              `salary2` , 
              `salary3`, 
              (@total:=@total+ `salary1` + `salary2` + `salary3`) as TSalary  
       FROM `Worker`, (select @total:=0) t 
       ORDER BY `Date` ASC ) AS `some_worker`  
WHERE (TSalary -(`salary1` + `salary2` + `salary3`))  <= 1500;

+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| ssn | name  | salary1 | salary2 | salary3 |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| 3   | Sumit |     250 |     150 |     100 |
| 4   | Harsh |     500 |    -150 |     900 |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*notice:* only two are selected because including third means more than N (= 1500).

Now suppose `N = 2000` :(*and as I calculated above I guess two row should be select*)

```
SELECT `ssn`, `name`, `salary1` , `salary2` , `salary3` 
FROM ( SELECT `ssn`, 
              `name`, 
              `salary1` , 
              `salary2` , 
              `salary3`, 
              (@total:=@total+ `salary1` + `salary2` + `salary3`) as TSalary  
       FROM `Worker`, (select @total:=0) t 
       ORDER BY `Date` ASC ) AS `some_worker`  
WHERE (TSalary -(`salary1` + `salary2` + `salary3`))  <= 2000;

+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| ssn | name  | salary1 | salary2 | salary3 |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| 3   | Sumit |     250 |     150 |     100 |
| 4   | Harsh |     500 |    -150 |     900 |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| 5   | ONE   |     100 |     170 |     100 |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This query working fine for this example but may be should for long table but this the one way you get your work done.

Give it a Try!!

<sub>Also, you can change equality condition in outer condition as you desire( I have bit confusion about your threshold definition. It might be good if you ask with an example)</sub>